# PL/SQL compile errors

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am facing the below errors for this PL/SQL stored procedure package when I attempt to compile it. I have taken the shell from another source and adapted for my needs I am not sure where else I need to create this?  I am very new to PL/SQL...

```
Package Body DEPLETION_ERRORS_MONTHLY_PKG compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
0/0       PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/16      PLS-00201: identifier 'DEPLETION_ERRORS_MONTHLY_PKG' must be declared
1/16      PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'DEPLETION_ERRORS_MONTHLY_PKG' without its specification
Errors: check compiler log


create or replace PACKAGE BODY  "DEPLETION_ERRORS_MONTHLY_PKG" AS
PROCEDURE RUN_SQL( OFF_Set IN NUMBER,

P_ERP_TBL  OUT XXTRANING_ERPTASK_TBL_TYPE,

STATUS OUT VARCHAR2)

IS

BEGIN

Select   XXTRAINING_ERPTASK_REC_TYPE

(

subinventory,
source_code||'-'||trx_reference (source_casenum_line), 
item_number,
item_description, 
error_msg,
filename,
creation_date,
quantity_used,
quantity_wasted,
INV_ITEM_FLAG,
INV_CATEGORY_NAME
)

BULK COLLECT INTO P_ERP_TBL from TGC_INT016_INV_DEPL_FBDI

where 1=1 
 and status='ERROR' 
 and creation_date >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) 
 and creation_date < trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
ORDER BY CREATION_DATE
OFFSET OFF_Set ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY;

STATUS:='SUCCESS';

COMMIT;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN

STATUS:='FAIL';

END;

END DEPLETION_ERRORS_MONTHLY_PKG;
```

Comment: You need to create and compile the package specification for this body. A .pks file

Comment: Or maybe you don't even need a package, and just want a procedure?

Comment: I've created the package specification already. I am still facing these errors...

Comment: Perhaps the package specification is invalid. Please post a complete test case that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the package's specification and compile it before attempting to compile the package's body again.

You can check if the package specification is in the database.

SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'DEPLETION_ERRORS_MONTHLY_PKG'
AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE';

If the query returns no results, it means that the package specification does not exist.

If the specification exists, there may be an error in the specification . You can check the error with this query.

SELECT *
FROM ALL_ERRORS
WHERE NAME = 'DEPLETION_ERRORS_MONTHLY_PKG'
AND TYPE = 'PACKAGE';

Answer (score 0):

This is the key:

```
1/16      PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'DEPLETION_ERRORS_MONTHLY_PKG' without its specification
```

When working with packages, you must have package specification. Package body is optional.

In your case, you have just the opposite - you tried to create a body, but there's no specification.

I certainly don't have that package in my schema, so - if I try to create body first, I get the same error as you:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY depletion_errors_monthly_pkg AS
  2    PROCEDURE run_sql( off_set    IN  NUMBER,
  3                       p_erp_tbl  OUT xxtraning_erptask_tbl_type,
  4                       status     OUT VARCHAR2)
  5    IS
  6    BEGIN
  7      null;
  8    END run_sql;
  9  END depletion_errors_monthly_pkg ;
 10  /

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

SQL>
SQL> show err
Errors for PACKAGE BODY DEPLETION_ERRORS_MONTHLY_PKG:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0      PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/14     PLS-00201: identifier 'DEPLETION_ERRORS_MONTHLY_PKG' must be
         declared

1/14     PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'DEPLETION_ERRORS_MONTHLY_PKG'
         without its specification

SQL>
```

---

Presuming procedure code is correctly written, all you need is to first create **package specification** (you said you have it; even if you do, it is invalid. Shouldn't be too difficult to create it properly):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE  depletion_errors_monthly_pkg AS
  2    PROCEDURE run_sql( off_set    IN  NUMBER,
  3                       p_erp_tbl  OUT xxtraning_erptask_tbl_type,
  4                       status     OUT VARCHAR2);
  5  END depletion_errors_monthly_pkg ;
  6  /

Package created.
```

Now create package specification (i.e. run code you posted in question). I don't have your tables nor procedures (and don't really feel like creating them), but - as I said - if procedure code is OK, everything should compile:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY depletion_errors_monthly_pkg AS
  2    PROCEDURE run_sql( off_set    IN  NUMBER,
  3                       p_erp_tbl  OUT xxtraning_erptask_tbl_type,
  4                       status     OUT VARCHAR2)
  5    IS
  6    BEGIN
  7      null;
  8    END run_sql;
  9  END depletion_errors_monthly_pkg ;
 10  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

---

By the way, setting `OUT` parameter value to `FAIL` isn't really helpful. You do know that something went wrong, but you have no idea what it was. Perhaps you'd rather just let Oracle raise the error, or - at least - return `SQLERRM`.